# undefined method `scoped' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line of code in my controller

```
timesheet_entries_pages, @timesheet_entries = paginate TimesheetEntry, 
  :per_page => 25,
  :conditions => [@conditions.keys.join(" AND "), *@conditions.values],
  :order => @order`
```

I am getting this error

> undefined method `scoped' for # Did you mean? scope unscoped

I don't have any method called "scoped" in any of my controllers or models.This is warning shown for pagination.
This is the error shown in my view

> ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "#paginate with a Symbol and/or find options is depreceted and will be removed. Use a scope instead."

```
klass = arg.is_a?(Symbol) ? arg.to_s.classify.constantize : arg
  scope = klass.scoped(finder_options)
  paginate(scope, options)
end
```

and also this the warning  shown in my terminal

> DEPRECATION WARNING: #paginate with a Symbol and/or find options is depreceted and will be removed. Use a scope instead. (called from deprecated_paginate at /ruby-test/redmine/lib/redmine/pagination.rb:137)

could someone help me with this and let me know if there is a way to re-write this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. It's hard for us to debug code that you haven't included ;) Can you please edit your question and paste in the relevant code snippets here? Obviously... some code somewhere has the word `scoped` being used... I don't see that code anywhere. You talk about the controller code, but have only shown us literally one line of code - can you please show us the rest of the relevant action?

Comment: has to do with your way of pagination...